# Why Am I Getting An Error In My Where Clause With An Array?

Tags: sql

I'm working on an SQL query that looks at a field that is an array of strings and pulls out all rows that have a specific string in the array. It would look like:

```
SELECT array FROM table WHERE array in ('String')
```

but I keep getting the error `"No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY; INT64 = UINT64; UINT64 = INT64"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/). Please also **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question

Comment: In Postgres you would need to write `where 'String' = any(array)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Could you put your table sample data  and the result you expect here